# C#: Videos download corrupted?

Tags: c#, .net

Each video I download, downloads at null length, and 145kb in size. When opening it to try and play it, it tells me its corrupted. Works fine when visiting the URL.

Tried from different sites and the same happens. Nothing on Google or any other Q&A site.

```
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), fileName);
```

Comment: What the URL? It could be a stream not a file.

Comment: It's not a stream, I've tried it on over 100 URL's on many different sites.

Comment: whats the filename, specifically the extension

Comment: `tumblr_nu2ou8wD0D1rnrk4b.mp4`

Comment: Could you please provide an URL of requested media file.